# Moving Parallels Desktop 8 to 9

Tags: parallels-desktop, macos

I was happily using PD 8.0 . Then I upgraded to Yosemite 10.10 and now Parallels 8.0 does not work anymore.
Did some search and looks like they have fixed it for Parallels 9.0
So I have to upgrade, Ok Fine.
BUT is there is a way I can skip re-installing everything again on PD 9.0 and somehow copy whatever I have from 8.0 to 9.0 ?

Comment: I disagree with the close vote as this is regarding moving data between two versions of app regardless of the version of OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just worked :)
Upgraded to 9.0...It automatically just worked. I needed to do nothing really.